# Error in Python when importing sklearn ..cannot import name 'Logger' from 'joblib.logger'

Tags: python, logging, scikit-learn, import, error-handling

This is the error I get when I run the following command: `from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix`

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Logger' from 'joblib.logger' (C:\ ... \Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\logger_*init*_.py)

I searched the web already to find a solution but nothing fits. For example, I tried to reinstall sklearn: `conda install -c anaconda scikit`

but still get the same error.

Any idea what the issue is here?

Those are the docs under C:...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\joblib\logger
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by updateing the Anaconda Navigator (Anaconda3) version.